# How do I declare a friend function for a class?

Tags: c++, function, class, friend

**Off-Topic: I want to ask, is this the right place to ask this kind of question?**

**What would be a more appropriate place to ask this kind of "naive" questions? I would like a website or something. Thank you. Now my problem:**

I have the task to write the **check_name** function ([this](https://practice.geeksforgeeks.org/problems/c-friend-function/1) problem).

I get the error: *'first_name' was not declared in this scope* **SOLVED**

EDIT: I just realized this is not enough and I have to remove every char after I find one in the string...

Here is the code. Thank you.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class student
{
private:
    string first_name;
    string last_name;

public:
    void set_name(string f, string l)
    {
        first_name = f;
        last_name = l;
    }

    friend void check_name(student k);
};

bool isInside(const string &str, char c)
{
    return str.find(c) != string::npos;
}

void check_name(student k)
{
    bool ok = true;
    for(int i = 0; i < first_name.size(); i++)
    {
        if(!isInside(last_name, first_name[i])) 
        {
            ok = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (ok) cout << "ANAGRAM" << endl;
    else cout << "NOT ANAGRAM" << endl;
}

int main()
{
    int t;
    cin >> t;
    while (t--)
    {
        string f, l;
        cin >> f >> l;
        student s;
        s.set_name(f, l);
        check_name(s);
    }
}
```

Comment: How would you access the students variables from a non-friend function?

Comment: `second_name` is not declared anywhere, and you probably want to use `k.first_name`. Also consider using references.

Comment: Ohh, yes, that was a mistake **second name** instead of **last_name**. and yes, I was measing the k. Thank you.

Comment: @JhonWillson Also, please feel free to use whitespace in your code.

Comment: `Off-Topic: I want to ask, is this the right place to ask this kind of question?` Yes, SO is fine, as long as you show that you did your research, gave your best effort in _[asking a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)_, and attaching _[a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)_ where appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

You want to use

```
void check_name(student k)
{
    bool ok = true;
    for (int i = 0; i < k.first_name.size(); i++)
//                      ^^
    {
        if (!isInside(k.last_name, k.first_name[i]))
//                    ^^           ^^
        {
            ok = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (ok) cout << "ANAGRAM" << endl;
    else cout << "NOT ANAGRAM" << endl;
}
```

Since your `check_name()` only reads `k` you might want to pass it as `student const&`.